# Sorting a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionaries, that looks something like this:

```
"abc": {
    "name": "Joey",
    "order": 3
    },
"def": {
    "name": "Allen",
    "order": 2
    },
"ghi": {
    "name": "Tim",
    "order": 1
    }
```

Now, I would like to sort this dictionary according to the "order" value.

Meaning, the sorted dictionary will look like:

```
"ghi": {
    "name": "Tim",
    "order": 1
    }
"def": {
    "name": "Allen",
    "order": 2
    },
"abc": {
    "name": "Joey",
    "order": 3
    }
```

How can I do this?
I found ways to sort a list of dictionaries, but not a dictionary of dictionaries.

Comment: You cannot sort a dictionary without using `OrderedDict` or converting into a list.

Comment: A `dict` is always unsorted.

Comment: The answers in [Python: sorting a dictionary of lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217251/python-sorting-a-dictionary-of-lists?rq=1) can easily be adapted to dict of dicts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) to sort by "order" and [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to store the result,

```
import collections

d = {
    "abc": {
        "name": "Joey",
        "order": 3
        },
    "def": {
        "name": "Allen",
        "order": 2
        },
    "ghi": {
        "name": "Tim",
        "order": 1
        }
    }

result = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t:t[1]["order"]))

# Output
print(result)
OrderedDict([('ghi', {'name': 'Tim', 'order': 1}), 
            ('def', {'name': 'Allen', 'order': 2}), 
            ('abc', {'name': 'Joey', 'order': 3})])
```

Comment: This can also print `'ghi', {'order': 1, 'name': 'Tim'}`, though, which may or may not be relevant.

Comment: How would I sort by multiple columns i.e. 'order' descending and then 'name'?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what exactly it is you are trying to accomplish. If you want to do something along the following lines, then without using OrderedDict:

```
dct_of_dcts = {
    "abc":
        {
            "name": "Joey",
            "order": 3
        },
    "def":
        {
            "name": "Allen",
            "order": 2
        },
    "ghi":
        {
            "name": "Tim",
            "order": 1
        }}

for k, v in sorted(dct_of_dcts.items(), key=lambda e: e[1]["order"]):
    print(k, v)
```

Will print either:

```
ghi {'name': 'Tim', 'order': 1}
def {'name': 'Allen', 'order': 2}
abc {'name': 'Joey', 'order': 3}
```

Or:

```
ghi {'order': 1, 'name': 'Tim'}
def {'order': 2, 'name': 'Allen'}
abc {'order': 3, 'name': 'Joey'}
```

In case you just want to output/print the dictionary of dictionaries in the exact order you specified, this would work:

```
for k, v in sorted(dct_of_dcts.items(), key=lambda e: e[1]["order"]):
    print(k, sorted(v.items()))
```

Output:

```
ghi [('name', 'Tim'), ('order', 1)]
def [('name', 'Allen'), ('order', 2)]
abc [('name', 'Joey'), ('order', 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from _collections import OrderedDict
d = {"abc":{"name":"Joey","order":3},
     "def":{"name":"Allen","order":2},
     "ghi":{"name":"Tim","order":1}}
_sorted = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]["order"]))
```

Then:

```
print(_sorted)
OrderedDict([('ghi', {'order': 1, 'name': 'Tim'}), ('def', {'order': 2, 'name': 'Allen'}), ('abc', {'order': 3, 'name': 'Joey'})])
```

And:

```
print(_sorted["ghi"])
{'order': 1, 'name': 'Tim'}
```

dictionaries are unordered, if you want one that is ordered you have to use `OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OrderedDict

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dic = { 'abc': { 'name': 'Joey', 'order': 3 }, 'def': { 'name': 'Allen', 'order': 2 }, 'ghi': { 'name': 'Tim', 'order': 1 } }

order_dic = OrderedDict(sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['order'], reverse=False))
```

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is not like a list - it has no particular 'order'. It is simply a collection of keys and their respective values, so dictionaries cannot be sorted.

If you wish to read more about it, the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) give a good overview of the datatype.