# How would I sort a dictionary of named dictionaries by a value in Python?

Tags: python

Here is an example of a list

```
accounts = {
     "user1": {
        "password": "test",
        "won": 8,
        "lost": 1,
        "colour": "green"
    },
    "user2": {
        "password": "test",
        "won": 12,
        "lost": 4,
        "colour": "blue"
    },
    "user3": {
        "password": "test",
        "won": 18,
        "lost": 1,
        "colour": "blue"
    }}
```

How would I go about sorting these by 'won'?
I just cannot seem to figure it out.
Thanks!

Comment: @mkrieger1 this is a dictionary of dictionaries, not a list of dictionaries

Comment: "Here is an example of a list" No, it isn't.

Comment: How about we choose this as duplicate target then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42398375/sorting-a-dictionary-of-dictionaries-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the `sorted` function with a custom key.

```
var = {"user2": {
        "password": "test",
        "won": 12,
        "lost": 4,
        "colour": "blue"
    },
    "user1": {
        "password": "test",
        "won": 8,
        "lost": 1,
        "colour": "green"
    },
    "user3": {
        "password": "test",
        "won": 18,
        "lost": 1,
        "colour": "blue"
    }}

result = sorted(var.items(),key=lambda x: x[1]["won"])
print(dict(result))
```

Output

```
{'user1': 
    {'password': 'test', 'won': 8, 'lost': 1, 'colour': 'green'}, 
'user2': 
    {'password': 'test', 'won': 12, 'lost': 4, 'colour': 'blue'}, 
'user3': 
    {'password': 'test', 'won': 18, 'lost': 1, 'colour': 'blue'}
}
```