# How to order a dictionary by its value, which is an array of 3 values?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a dictionary like this:

```
{'GBR': [0, 0, 1],
 'TPE': [0, 1, 1],
 'KOR': [3, 1, 0],
 'CHN': [3, 1, 2],
 'AUS': [0, 0, 1],
 'UKR': [0, 0, 1],
 'JPN': [0, 1, 0],
 'ITA': [1, 0, 0]}
```

The values in this dictionary are arrays of 3 values. I want to sort it in all three values where index 0 takes first priority, index 1 takes second priority and index 2 takes final priority

This is what I would expect out:

```
[('CHN', [3, 1, 2]),
 ('KOR', [3, 1, 0]),
 ('ITA', [1, 0, 0]),
 ('TPE', [0, 1, 1]),
 ('JPN', [0, 1, 0]),
 ('UKR', [0, 0, 1]),
 ('GBR', [0, 0, 1]),
 ('AUS', [0, 0, 1])]
```

How can I do this using the `sort` function? I've tried using `lambda`, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: sorting a dictionary of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217251/python-sorting-a-dictionary-of-lists)

Comment: *list* not array. Anyway, what you are describing is exactly how lists are already ordered, i.e. lexicographically. So just sort by the values...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
d = {
 'GBR': [0, 0, 1],
 'TPE': [0, 1, 1],
 'KOR': [3, 1, 0],
 'CHN': [3, 1, 2],
 'AUS': [0, 0, 1],
 'UKR': [0, 0, 1],
 'JPN': [0, 1, 0],
 'ITA': [1, 0, 0]}

sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Result:

```
[('CHN', [3, 1, 2]), ('KOR', [3, 1, 0]), ('ITA', [1, 0, 0]), ('TPE', [0, 1, 1]), ('JPN', [0, 1, 0]), ('GBR', [0, 0, 1]), ('AUS', [0, 0, 1]), ('UKR', [0, 0, 1])]
```