# How do I sort a dictionary by a part of the dictionary values?

Tags: python

I have a .txt file with the following format:

```
Name A
2019-02-04 15:29:10
First Line of info
Second line of info
Third line of info

Name B
2019-01-04 12:21:10
First Line of info
Second line of info
Third line of info
```

I have converted into this file into a dictionary with the first line being the key and the rest of the value as a list using the following code:

```
import itertools as it
dict = {}

with open('filenamehere') as f:
    while True:
        try:
            p = next(f).rstrip()
            dict[p] = list(l.rstrip() for l in it.takewhile(lambda line: line != '\n', f))
            
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

This creates a dictionary with `{'Name A': ['2019-02-04 15:29:10','First line of info','Second line of info','third line of info']` and so on. I was then able to sort this dictionary to alphabetical order and display it with a similar format as the original text file:

```
sorted_dict= {}

sorted_keys = sorted(dict.keys(), key=lambda x:x.lower())

for key in sorted_keys:
        sorted_dict.update({key: dict[key]})
        
for name, details in list(sorted_dict.items()):
    print(f"{name}\n" + '\n'.join(details), "\n")
```

Now my question is how do I sort this dictionary by latest timestamp and then print it with a similar format as the original text file?

Comment: How did you generate `sorted_keys`? Do the same, but sort by timestamp instead of key value (the `sort` function has a `key` argument!).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: sorting a dictionary of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217251/python-sorting-a-dictionary-of-lists)

Comment: @mkrieger1 That question is about obtaining a sorted *list*. OP wants a sorted *dictionary* (which is now possible, but wasn’t yet when the other question was asked).

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph 'm quite unsure of how to sort it by timestamp instead of key value

Comment: You pass a `key` function similar to the one shown in the answer to the question I've linked to `sorted` to obtain your `sorted_keys` and then you use the rest of your code just like before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sorted_dict = {}
for key, value in sorted(original_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1][0], reverse=True):
        sorted_dict[key] = value
```

where `x[1][0]` represents first item of the dictionary values, which is what I believe you want to sort the dictionary on. The reverse argument is optional and defaults to False if not provided.

Comment: Would there be any problems if I sort it by the latest timestamp by adding reverse = True? I'm not sure if any potential problems will happen because its a timestamp

Comment: I missed the part where you asked for 'latest'. Yes of course you can use the reverse parameter. I've updated my answer as well

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Python: sorting a dictionary of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217251/python-sorting-a-dictionary-of-lists), you first gonna need to convert the timestamp from *a string* to a *Time Object*, then compare them.

[`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) can do the job: Convert the string to a **Time object** by a specific format. For example:

```py
In [13]: a = datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-02-04 15:29:10', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
In [14]: b = datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-02-04 15:30:10', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
In [15]: b > a
Out[15]: True
```

Then you can sort your dictionary with it as your key, solution from the answer I mentioned. Just execute `dict()` as function to convert the result to a dict:

```py
In [17]: dict(sorted(sorted_dict.items(), key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[1][0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
Out[17]:
{'Name B': ['2019-01-04 12:21:10',、
'First Line of info',
'Second line of info',
'Third line of info'],
'Name A': ['2019-02-04 15:29:10',
'First Line of info',
'Second line of info',
'Third line of info']} 

In [18]:
```

Comment: Well, actually, seems there's no difference between sorting a timestamp based on string format or time format...because something like `15:29:10` also looks larger than `12:21:10` in a string comparison..._so why did I answer this_

Comment: @KonradRudolph Ah yes, I forgot about that. Edited my answer and thanks for mention it.