# How to sort a dictionary by values which contain lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this dictionary:

```
Dict = {'Key1': ['LONG', 1], 'Key3': ['LONG', 7], 'Key4': ['LONG_A', 9]}
```

Each value of the dictionary contains a tuple with a string and an int value.
I would like to sort this dictionary by the int value (in descending order).

The result should be:

```
Expected = {'Key4': ['LONG_A', 9],'Key3': ['LONG', 7],'Key1': ['LONG', 1]}
```

Comment: First of all, there is not much meaning for sorting a dictionary. In newer versions dicts do maintain insertion order but in general are hash based and not ordered. Second the values are lists, not tuples...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: sorting a dictionary of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217251/python-sorting-a-dictionary-of-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) in python

Use this code:

```
sorted(Dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1],reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
[('Key4', ['LONG_A', 9]), ('Key3', ['LONG', 7]), ('Key1', ['LONG', 1])]
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it works for you :)

Comment: Thanks Subbu, but unfortunately it does work if I add more values. For example: Dict = {'Key1': ['LONG', 1], 'Key3': ['LONG', 70], 'Key4': ['LONG_A', 9],'Key5': ['LONG_A', 3]} sorted(Dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True). This will return [('Key4','LONG_A', 9]),
 ('Key5', ['LONG_A', 3]),
 ('Key3', ['LONG', 70]),
 ('Key1', ['LONG', 1])] Here Key3 should show up the first one

Comment: This just sorts according to the list as a whole, and not according to the int values. Depending on the strings, this might give false results...

Comment: Replacing `x` with `(k, v)`, and then `x[1]` with `v` would make it much more clear